# Replacing specific content with other content using javascript in a td element

Tags: javascript, html

Anyone know how I can replace the content of td tag when content is JC with John????
Given it a go but can't get it to fully work.

```
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<th>A</th>
<th>B</th>
<th>C</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>PQ</td>
<td>ML</td>
<td>JC</td>
</tr>
</table>

<script>
$('td').filter(function () {
        return $.trim($(this).text()) === "JC";
        }).innerHTML.replace("JC","John");
<script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use contains: http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

```
$('td:contains("JC")').text("john");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z6pJG/

Comment: `contains("JC")` - needs quotes

Comment: Thanks! Worked a treat!

Answer (score 1):

Makes use of [the property of `.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/#text-functionindex--text) that if given a function, the return of the function will replace the text.

```
$('td').text(function (idx, text) {
     if($.trim(text) === "JC") {
        return "John";
     }
})
```

Can also (probably) be written:

```
$('td:contains("JC")').text("John");
```